# How to install Nvidia Parallel NSight (Nexus) for VS2010 without having installed VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cuda, nvidia, nsight

Is there a way to install Parallel NSight and use it with Visual Studio 2010 without having VS2008 SP1 installed?
The setup checks if VS2008 is installed and won't continue if not.
I know there is no official support for VS2010, but I found on a forum a small application that can integrate Nexus into VS2010 and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently someone at the Nsight forum (Nvidia) was able to get it to work.

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=161096

Answer (score 0):

I just checks some registry keys - if you can figure out which ones it checks, you're golden :)